# How to recover mysql root password in MacOS

Tags: mysql, database, macos, mamp, root

I start my MAMP and try to connect to my MySQL server via `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`, I tried all the possible password that I think it is correct, but for some reasons it still didn't like it, so I think I forgot it somehow. I need help.

---

## Try #1

Enter all the possible passwords

`MySQL -u root -h localhost -p`

Enter password: <---*I've tried almost 10 possible passwords*

I got

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

---

## Try #2

Enter possible passwords

`MySQL -u root -h localhost`

I got

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
>
> ---

## Try #3

`MySQL.server stop`

I got

> ERROR! MySQL server PID file could not be found!

I'm trying to run this

`mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &`

I got

---

## Try #4

`mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &`

I got

```
[1] 72194
  ~  2017-10-04T12:13:42.6NZ mysqld_safe Logging to '/usr/local/var/mysql/BH-MacBook-Pro-15-512GB.local.err'.
2017-10-04T12:13:42.6NZ mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/var/mysql
2017-10-04T12:13:44.6NZ mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /usr/local/var/mysql/BH-MacBook-Pro-15-512GB.local.pid ended
```

Open a new tab

`MySQL -u root`

I still get

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

---

## Try #5

Close my MAMP application, and run this

`mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &`

I got

```
[1] 72194
  ~  2017-10-04T12:13:42.6NZ mysqld_safe Logging to '/usr/local/var/mysql/BH-MacBook-Pro-15-512GB.local.err'.
2017-10-04T12:13:42.6NZ mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/var/mysql
2017-10-04T12:13:44.6NZ mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /usr/local/var/mysql/BH-MacBook-Pro-15-512GB.local.pid ended
```

Open a new tab

`MySQL -u root`

I still get

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

---

I don't what else to try anymore.

*I can't really set the root password because I can't even get in.*

---

This is the process of my MySQL

`ps aux | grep MySQL`

```
bheng            95850   0.2  1.0  2869440 175404   ??  S     8:48AM   0:00.28 /usr/local/opt/mysql/bin/mysqld --basedir=/usr/local/opt/mysql --datadir=/usr/local/var/mysql --plugin-dir=/usr/local/opt/mysql/lib/plugin --bind-address=127.0.0.1 --log-error=/usr/local/var/mysql/bh-mbp-15-512gb.ad.benu.net.err --pid-file=/usr/local/var/mysql/bh-mbp-15-512gb.ad.benu.net.pid
_mysql             124   0.0  0.0  2864848   4040   ??  Ss   22Sep17   0:32.26 /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld --user=_mysql --basedir=/usr/local/mysql --datadir=/usr/local/mysql/data --plugin-dir=/usr/local/mysql/lib/plugin --log-error=/usr/local/mysql/data/mysqld.local.err --pid-file=/usr/local/mysql/data/mysqld.local.pid --keyring-file-data=/usr/local/mysql/keyring/keyring --early-plugin-load=keyring_file=keyring_file.so
bheng            95863   0.0  0.0  2423384    396 s009  R+    8:48AM   0:00.00 grep mysql
bheng            95749   0.0  0.0  2448756   2496   ??  S     8:48AM   0:00.03 /bin/sh /usr/local/opt/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe --bind-address=127.0.0.1 --datadir=/usr/local/var/mysql
bheng            66379   0.0  0.1  2696936   9304   ??  S     8:06AM   0:00.51 /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld --basedir=/Applications/MAMP/Library --datadir=/Applications/MAMP/db/mysql --plugin-dir=/Applications/MAMP/Library/lib/plugin --log-error=/Applications/MAMP/logs/mysql_error_log.err --pid-file=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.pid --socket=/Applications/MAMP/tmpmysql/mysql.sock --port=8889
bheng            66263   0.0  0.0  2446708   2100   ??  S     8:06AM   0:00.02 /bin/sh /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe --port=8889 --socket=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock --pid-file=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.pid --log-error=/Applications/MAMP/logs/mysql_error_log
```

~

Answer (score 11):

This is how you can do it in macOS Sierra, probably you install it via [pkg](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/osx-installation-pkg.html) and in the system preferences have an icon for MySQL, something like this:

[image]

If is up and running open a terminal and run this command:

```
pgrep -fl mysql
```

That will help you to find the path of `mysqld` and the current command used to start the server, the output could be something like this:

```
6283 /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld --user=_mysql --basedir=/usr/local/mysql --datadir=/usr/local/mysql/data --plugin-dir=/usr/local/mysql/lib/plugin --log-error=/usr/local/mysql/data/mysqld.local.err --pid-file=/usr/local/mysql/data/mysqld.local.pid
```

Next step is to stop MySQL, you can do this by clicking on the System Preferences menu and click on the `Stop MySQL Server` button, Once is stoped within a terminal you will need to start again the server but with some extra options, something like this:

```
sudo /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld \
  --skip-grant-tables \
  --skip-networking \
  --user=_mysql --basedir=/usr/local/mysql --datadir=/usr/local/mysql/data --plugin-dir=/usr/local/mysql/lib/plugin --log-error=/usr/local/mysql/data/mysqld.local.err --pid-file=/usr/local/mysql/data/mysqld.local.pid
```

It is indeed the same command from the output of `pgrep -fl mysql` but in this case, you just need to add:

```
--skip-grant-tables --skip-networking
```

After doing that you will notice that the menu from the System Preferences is Green again and MySQL should be up and running, now you can try to login and change password:

```
mysql -uroot
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
mysql> SET PASSWORD FOR root@'localhost' = PASSWORD('secret');
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
mysql> exit
```

Stop and start again MySQL from the System Preference panel and it should be working now with the new password.

Answer (score 11):

Please follow the steps in same sequence.

Make sure, your MySQL server is down. Execute below command :

```
mysql.server stop
```

Then, start MySQL server in safe mode

```
mysql.server start --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking
```

Then, connect to MySQL using `root` user.

```
mysql -u root
```

Change the database from `none` to `mysql`

```
MariaDB [(none)]> use mysql;
Database changed
```

Update both `authentication_string` and `password` column with same password as shown below (if you get column not found error then remove one )

```
MariaDB [mysql]> update user set authentication_string=PASSWORD('password'), password=PASSWORD('password') where user='root';

MariaDB [mysql]> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
MariaDB [mysql]> quit;
```

Now, stop everything including `MySQL` server and MAMP application as well.

And, search for **`config.inc.php`** file inside your MAMP folder (you could use <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd> and search this file).

You may not have privilege to change this file. After updating the privilege of the file you need to look for `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password']` and update the password value as shown below.

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'password';
```

Save this file and restart everything in normal mode. And try connecting `root` user with new password as shown below :

```
mysql -uroot -ppassword
```

Comment: Don't enter the password on the command line as it will persist in command history (if you have that configured, I'd guess that you do). Leave the "password" off and be prompted for it.

Answer (score 2):

You have to reset the MySQL root password as follow :

```
/etc/init.d/mysql stop
/usr/sbin/mysqld --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking &
mysql -u root

mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
mysql> SET PASSWORD FOR root@'localhost' = PASSWORD('new_password');
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
mysql> exit;

service mysql restart
```

And then, you will be able to connect using :
mysql -u root -p
Your password

Comment: `-bash: /etc/init.d/mysql: No such file or directory`

Comment: `/etc/init.d/mysql` is the command to start or stop mysql deamon. If you have other ways to stop the database: use that

Comment: You can use "service mysql stop" instead.

Comment: I use MAMP. Should I just close MAMP application ?

Comment: The "stop" command needs to be replaced by whatever takes on the OS to kill `mysqld`.

Answer (score 1):

Follow those instructions and you should be fine:

https://svendeswan.wordpress.com/2016/01/26/mysql-reset-root-password-without-knowing-it-mac-mamp/

which is based on this one:

https://www.tech-otaku.com/local-server/resetting-mamp-mysql-root-user-password/