# Can not create a Schema - MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am having the following problem. I am trying to create a new schema from workbench but I am getting this.

[image]

The connection in mysql through the terminal works fine.

```
Theodosioss-MacBook-Pro:~ theodosiostziomakas$ mysql -u theo -p
Enter password:
Welcome to the MySQL monitor. Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 8
Server version: 8.0.13 MySQL Community Server - GPL


Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.


Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.


Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.


mysql>
```

To make sure that I have the correct user

```
mysql> select current_user();
+----------------+
| current_user() |
+----------------+
| theo@localhost |
+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)


mysql>
```

I am typing **show grants for 'theo'@'localhost';**

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for theo@localhost |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO `theo`@`localhost` |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `photo_app`.* TO `theo`@`localhost` |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Of course I need to change the privileges.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'theo'@'localhost';
```

And get this back

```
Access denied for user 'theo'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Any ideas how to fix this problem? I could have deleted mysql, but I am sure there is a solution. The machine I am using Macbook Pro.

Comment: Yes `theo` only has GRANT access on a database called `photo_app` and not on the new database youare trying to create

Comment: You need to use the `root` account to add more privileges to `theo`.

Comment: @RiggsFolly So how can i change this?

Comment: Like @Barmar said, you need to use the `root` (SuperUser) account or whichever account has been given the correct privilages to create and grant privilages on new schemas

Comment: @RiggsFolly I forgot the root password and need to recover it somehow

Comment: See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29070501/regaining-access-to-lost-mysql-password-for-phpmyadmin-on-wamp/29073563#29073563) or many others you can find with a GOOGLE search on `stackoverflow: recover root password`

Comment: Ah you are a Mac user, [so try this answer instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46564719/how-to-recover-mysql-root-password-in-macos)